# Assign row column combinations in a dataframe to variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I regularly have the following issue.  Let's say I produce the following summary table from a dplyr chain:

```
dat = read.table(text = "treatment mean_pre sd_pre mean_post sd_post
DD  14.78429    20.65952    13.95886    18.86172
DR  10.50125    17.51840    21.33969    23.56563
RD  17.33781    19.19242    26.30031    26.10222
RR  24.44870    23.38217    26.74986    25.04986", header = T)
```

I then manually construct variables for use in future parts of the code like so:

```
dd_mean_pre = 14.78429
dd_sd_pre = 13.95886
dd_mean_post = 13.95886
dd_sd_post = 18.86172
dr_mean_pre = 10.50125
```

And so on, for all the cells in the dataframe.  Is there a faster way to dynamically assign the row and column combinations of this dataframe to variables in R?

Comment: Can you show the expected

Comment: The expected result is a list of variables assigned to the respective cells in the dataframe (as depicted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we can pivot into 'long' format and then `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out  <- dat %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = -treatment) %>% 
        mutate(treatment = tolower(treatment)) %>%
        unite(trtname, treatment, name)
```

If we need it as different objects (not recommended)

```
library(tibble)
deframe(out) %>%
     as.list %>% 
     list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

The objects are created in the global env

```
rr_mean_pre
#[1] 24.4487
dr_mean_post
#[1] 21.33969
```

Comment: Ah this is brilliant.  Is there any way to assign the columns in trtname to actual variables in R?  So that I can reference them as objects?

Comment: @Parseltongue Thank you. Updated the post